# Split variable using multiple special characters - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable

```
var i = "my*text+val-ab/c"
```

I want to split it using special characters `*`, `+`, `-` and `/`. I mean, I want to generate:

```
var one = "my", var two = "text", var three = "val"
```

from the above variable.

How can I do this using jQuery and (or) Javascript?

```
var ret1 = id.split("+");
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you want to split by `,` - the comma character, or not? Also, can you have more than one of these at a time - for example `my**string` or `my*+string`?

Answer (score 3):

Try splitting on a character class containing all symbols:

```js
var i = "my*text+val-ab/c";
var parts = i.split(/[*,+=\/-]/);
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: I think you're missing `-`. Also, no need for `,`

Comment: You've forgot `-`)